# How to if on a 2 string types

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement

I need an **if condition** on a 2 types string:

1) "/A/Ababa"
2) "/A"

Something like this:

```
    if(myString is of the first type){
      must return Ababa
     }
```

then

```
    if(myString is of the second type){
      must return null
     }
```

How can i do correctly? Maybe Regex? Substring? Any other ideas?

Comment: What do these types mean? Do they have to be exact matches? Is that supposed to be a pattern?

Comment: Count number of slashes? Just check string length? Find index of last slash and use substring? It is unclear what you actually want. Also, it'd be great if you tried something yourself. Also, check out what MCVE is, for your next question.

Comment: "/A/Ababa" is a pattern... i don't need exact match but a match for a string of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on your bounds, but assuming your string always starts with `/` a single character and another `/`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/.(/(.*))?");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

if (m != null) {
   return m.group(2)
}
```

Comment: I can't if in this way... The string is not always the same, but could be something like "/C/Ccccc" or "/D/Dadada".

Comment: So you need a regex?  I will add an example.  You should really clarify your question.

Comment: Yes i need something like that! Thank u!